# Cordova reference missing on iOS build, but fine on android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, cordova

I am building a project with Cordova for iOS and Android platforms (cordova version 7.0.1 and platform iOS 4.5.1 and platform android 6.2.3). When I use the command `cordova run ios` or `cordova run android` I find that the iOS build will somehow not have embedded cordova.js and although the pages will load, none of my cordova plugins will work and the debugger shows the following error:

> exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova

If I manually include `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` in my index.html file and run the command again, everything works fine (although then android complains of a second declaration of cordova.js)

I would like to have one build where I don't have to constantly modify one or the other environment. Here are some other things I have noticed when running those commands:

1. I have verified that the index.html and three js files (app, manifest and vendor) are identical between their iOS and Android generated versions (in /platforms/ios/www and /platforms/android/assets/www respectively).
2. Also the other files present in each folder seem to match.

Because the appropriate files seem to match, I believe this bug is at the point where the command loads the bundle/app onto my iPhone or simulator, and as I said plugins will not work without force including it in the index.html file, but everything outside of plugins works fine in the app.

Comment: Cordova apps need to link the cordova.js in the index.html. If you are getting a duplicate cordova is because something else is adding it. Hard to tell what without seeing your code.

Comment: somehow, WITHOUT including it in my index.html file, cordova plugins still load and run fine in my android build. It is only with the IOS build I have to manually include it. (and when doing that, the android debugger complains about it being included TWICE as mentioned above)

Comment: what I say is, that is NOT the default Cordova behaviour, you must have something in your code that is adding the cordova.js in Android.

Comment: what is strange is, that when opening up the final archives for iOS or Android, NEITHER of them have a direct reference to cordova.js in the index.html file, yet android works and iOS does not (unless I manually include that reference). The cordova.js (and associated js) files are all in the same www directory in both builds, they are simply ignored in the iOS build and used in the android build.

Comment: and to reply directly to your earlier comment, yes that something in my code is ME. I am including the reference to make the iOS build work, which CAUSES the android build to complain about a dupe. If I build them separately, taking care to put it in for the iOS build and then take it out for the android build, neither will complain and both will work. But it should not have to be this way, they should both automatically work out of the box using the cordova run/build commands.

Comment: If you put it and then it says it's duplicated it's because something else is putting another one, making it duplicate. Anyway, it's impossible to know what is going on without seeing your code. I've created a new Cordova project and Android plugins don't work if there is no cordova.js linked.

Comment: both apps compiled vendor.js files (located in /js in the www folder) are identical, and they contain a reference to cordova.js, so that is where they are being included. But ios is ignoring this if I don't also include it in index.html. So there is something else going on here with the cordova run command or some config file I am unable to locate.